# How to Combine Changes after Separately Altering Remote and Local

Tags: git

I changed some files in my Github project remotely (added a README). However, I then altered other files (not the README) locally on my computer, which does not have the README file. What is the best way to combine the changes? How does git know which changes to keep--from the remote and local?

Appreciate any advice! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a normal git workflow. It's the same situation as if another developer pushed changes - you have remote changes and you want to integrate your changes on top of them. E.g.

Your repository looks like this

```
 A----B----C-----D
           ^     ^
           |     master
           |
           origin/master
```

the remote looks like this

```
 A----B----C-----E
                 ^
                 master
```

Fetch the remote changes `git fetch` and your local will look like this

```
 A----B----C-----D
            \    ^
             \   master
              \
               E
               ^
               origin/master
```

What you normally want is to integrate your changes in commit `D` on top of `E`. Use `git rebase origin/master`. You should not have conflicts, because you said that you touched different files in `E` and `D`. After the rebase your local repository looks like this:

```
 A----B----C-----E----D
                 ^    ^
                 |     master
                 |
                 origin/master
```

Now you can push your local changes to the remote repository `git push`.

The short way is to use

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

**EDIT**

> What if one touched the same files in E and D? I didn't do this, but how would that conflict be resolved?

If git rebase detects a conflict that it can't resolve it pauses and tells you to resolve the conflict manually. Do a `git status` to see where the conflicts are, resolve them and mark them resolved by staging them (`git add`). When you resolved all conflicts you can continue the rebase with `git rebase --continue`. Take a look at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase for details.

> It is possible that a merge failure will prevent this process from being completely automatic. You will have to resolve any such merge failure and run git rebase --continue. Another option is to bypass the commit that caused the merge failure with git rebase --skip. To check out the original  and remove the .git/rebase-apply working files, use the command git rebase --abort instead.

Comment: Thank you. What if one touched the same files in E and D? I didn't do this, but how would that conflict be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do a `git pull` on your local repository to bring everything up to date with the remote.

```
git pull
```

What that does is fetch from the remote repository any changes, and merges them into your current local branch.*

<sup>*:  The branch you're currently on, not any other branches.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1_ from your local machine stage the changes:

$ git add -A

$ git commit -m "a description of your changes"

this commands stages all modified or new files and commits them locally.

2 _ then: $ git pull

so you bring latest changes, git will auto-merge if it's needed.

3 _ finally to push all changes to remote repository:
$ git push

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm assuming you're only using "master" branch in both local and remote repos.